# WebServicesClientProtocol add EncodingType to Nonce in Security header

Tags: c#, .net, soap, ws-security, wse

Similar question: [How do I add an EncodingType attribute to the Nonce element of a UsernameToken in WSE 3.0 (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418506/how-do-i-add-an-encodingtype-attribute-to-the-nonce-element-of-a-usernametoken-i)

I'm trying to modify header that is send by `WebServicesClientProtocol` to service.
Unfortunately Microsoft's implementation of `WSSE Username and Token Security Spec 1.1` isn't compatible with standard and isn't sending `EncodingType` with `Nonce`.

In similar question I've linked on top solution was to disable `EncodingType` validation on server, but I'm not able to modify anything.

I've imported WSDL as Web Reference, I've changed base class to `WebServicesClientProtocol`

Then inside my code I'm doing this:

```
var client = new QueryClient();

SoapContext requestContext = client.RequestSoapContext;
requestContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;
var userToken = new UsernameToken(_userName, _password, PasswordOption.SendHashed);
requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(userToken);
X509SecurityToken signatureToken = GetSecurityToken();
requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(signatureToken);
MessageSignature sig = new MessageSignature(signatureToken);
requestContext.Security.Elements.Add(sig);
client.SetClientCredential(signatureToken);
client.SetClientCredential(new UsernameToken(_userName, _password, PasswordOption.SendHashed));
```

this creates request that is almost ideal, but Nonce hasn't got `EncodingType`:

```
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-096b3d09-bc08-4d9b-a561-c5c793dd7197">
    <wsse:Username>ws_test_user</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">XrFybEBGGqAIp2ybV6BbAdGa01U=</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce>gXsJgA6vV/HwY4pew9pi9Q==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2017-02-03T12:17:57Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

Nonce must have this attribute: `EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"`

How can I add this attribute? I'd like to avoid manually creating request because I must specify Username, Password, BinarySecurityToken and Signature. `Microsoft.Web.Services3` is creating all necessary elements for me, one thing missing is that attribute.

**EDIT:**

This is request I'm trying to create:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:dz="http://dom.query.api.com" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://dz.api.swd.zbp.pl/xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-E94CEB6F4708FB7C23148611494797612">
                <wsse:Username>my_login</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">XqEwZ/CxaBfFvh487TjvN8qD63c=</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">JzURe0CxvzRjmEcH/ndldw==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2017-02-09T09:42:27.976Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-E94CEB6F4708FB7C2314861149479517">MIIKnDCCB.........nmIngeg6d6TNI=</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature Id="SIG-E94CEB6F4708FB7C23148611494795311" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dz soap xsd" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-E94CEB6F4708FB7C23148611494795310">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dz xsd" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>mlABQuNUFOmLqsDswxXxQ6XnjpQ=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>lYhBHSQ/L...XL1HEbMQjJ/Q2Rvg==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-E94CEB6F4708FB7C2314861149479518">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="STR-E94CEB6F4708FB7C2314861149479519" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-E94CEB6F4708FB7C2314861149479517" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body wsu:Id="id-E94CEB6F4708FB7C23148611494795310" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <dz:query>
            <dz:param>
                <xsd:userQueryId>27467</xsd:userQueryId>
            </dz:param>
        </dz:query>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've send my request to service creator and he confirm that all I need is that `EncodingType` attribute in `Nonce`

Answer (score 0):

The EncodingType flag is according to the WSSE Username and Token Security Spec 1.1, which is the spec required by the version of the Apache CXF framework that this Java Web Service is using. .NET does not meet that spec. Luckily there was a flag in CXF to turn off the requirement. We did that and are now able to communicate.

Comment: Thank You for reply, unfortunately I'm unable to change WS, because it is delivered by external company and they refused to turn off that requirement.